# Does Maven transmit username/passwords in plaintext over http

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, nexus

If I have a username/password in my `settings.xml` file for a (Nexus) remote repository with an HTTP (not HTTPS) URL, will this username/password be sent in plaintext to the remote server?

I'm wondering if there's a potential security issue with our public-facing HTTP-only password-authenticated Nexus server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven uses HTTP Basic authentication to send the credentials. A typical HTTP header for this looks something along the lines of:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

Where `QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==` is actually a Base64-encoded representation of your `username:password` combination. This offers no security whatsoever, but it's not plain-text either.

For more details on HTTP Basic authentication, you can check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

Most build tools like Maven, Ant, Gradle, SBT, npm, use HTTP Basic. That's not as secure as it should be. Using it over HTTPS could make you feel more secure. :)